# Querying a JSON-Structure in Angular: Find the right index and get a certain property of it

Tags: json, angularjs, querying, angularjs-rootscope

Assume, following JSON Structure is existing:

```
[
  {
    "role_id": 1,
    "role_name": "Admin"
  },
  {
    "role_id": 2,
    "role_name": "Editor"
  }
]
```

and stored in **$rootScope.roles**.

What I need is:

```
$rootScope.roles[index -> where role_id == 2].rolename  // gets -> Editor
```

How can I do that in Angular?

Comment: Take a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462318/find-a-value-in-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript
Does it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ng-lodash** is an elegant way:

```
role_name = lodash.pluck(lodash.where($rootScope.roles,{'role_id': 2 }),'role_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to loop over the array and return the property of the object that matches the given id:

```
function getRoleName(roleId) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $rootScope.roles.length; i++) {
        if ($rootScope.roles[i].role_id == roleId) {
            return $rootScope.roles[i].role_name;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: that is OK but not an elegant solution, there must be a better way than a iteration loop, isn't it?

Comment: As I know, underscore has a method, maybe I have to include it, into the project?

Comment: I suppose... anyway underscore will loop the array behind the scenes... If you don't have a map there is no way to do it without a loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a more "single-line" solution, you can use JS array function `find`:

`($rootScope.roles.find(function (x) { return x.role_id == 2; }) || {}).role_name;`

When it is not found, `find` returns `null` so I substituted that possible result by `{}` so it does not throw an exception when accessing `null.role_name`. This way it will return `undefined` when the specified `role_id` is not found.

Note this method is a new technology and won't be available in every browser, more info in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Another "single-line" more stable solution would be to use `filter`:

`($rootScope.roles.filter(function (x) { return x.role_id == 2; })[0] || {}).role_name;`

This other method is more stable and can be found in every browser, more info in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter