# How to take first and only one object with specific property?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array with objects:

```
[{name:'test', lastname: 'test', gender:'f'},{name:'test1', lastname: 'test1', gender:'m'},{name:'test2', lastname: 'test2', gender:'m'}]
```

How to get first (and only 1) object from array with genger: 'm'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
var ar = [{name:'test', lastname: 'test', gender:'f'},{name:'test1', lastname: 'test1', gender:'m'},{name:'test2', lastname: 'test2', gender:'m'}];

var result = ar.find(function(e) {
  return e.gender == 'm';
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Note that `find` is not available in IE and lots of mobile browsers, as your link shows under 'Browser compatibility'

Answer (score 0):

Loop over your array and check if the item has `gender == 'm'` in each iteration. Could look like this:

```
function first_male(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].gender == 'm') {
            return data[i];
        }
     }
}

var data = [
    {name:'test', lastname: 'test', gender:'f'},
    {name:'test1', lastname: 'test1', gender:'m'},
    {name:'test2', lastname: 'test2', gender:'m'}
];
first_male(data); // Object {name: "test1", lastname: "test1", gender: "m"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

> The `find()` method returns a `value` in the array, if an element in the array satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) is returned.

```js
var array = [{name:'test', lastname: 'test', gender:'f'},{name:'test1', lastname: 'test1', gender:'m'},{name:'test2', lastname: 'test2', gender:'m'}];

console.log(array.find(a => a.gender ==='m'));
```

If not available, use [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill). Or

```js
var array = [{name:'test', lastname: 'test', gender:'f'},{name:'test1', lastname: 'test1', gender:'m'},{name:'test2', lastname: 'test2', gender:'m'}],
    element;

array.some(function (a) {
    if (a.gender === 'm') {
        element = a;
        return true;
    }
});
console.log(element);
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to loop on your array. There is a very similar thread here : [Find a value in an array of objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462318/find-a-value-in-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)
The return instruction will break out of the loop when a corresponding object is found.