# Javascript if html input value is in array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am working on a `HTML` chatbot and I need a way to check the users in put to see if it's in an array. I have tried already but it doesn't see to be working. I need it to take the users greets and store it into an array. Then, when the user enters any one of the greets in the array to reply with a random value from the array.

```js
var greet = [];
var questions = [];
var responses=[];
function greets(){
 var learn = document.getElementById("greets").value;
 if (learn == "finished"){
  document.cookie = 'greetings='+greet+'; expires=Wed, 1 Jan 2070 13:47:11 UTC; path=/'
 }else{
  greet.push(learn);
 };
};
function ques(){
 var learn = document.getElementById("ques").value;
 if (learn == "finished"){
  document.cookie = 'questions='+questions+'; expires=Wed, 1 Jan 2070 13:47:11 UTC; path=/'
 }else{
  questions.push(learn);
 };
};
function res(){
 var learn = document.getElementById("res").value;
 if (learn == "finished"){
  document.cookie = 'responses='+responses+'; expires=Wed, 1 Jan 2070 13:47:11 UTC; path=/'
 }else{
  responses.push(learn);
 };
};

var types = [{
   key: 'greet',
   data: greet
 }, {
   key: 'questions',
   data: questions
 }, {
   key: 'responses',
   data: responses
}];
function send(){
 
/* isExist method two arguements
   arr - array of values.
   str - string to be search.
*/
 
var msg = document.getElementById("msg");


if(types.indexOf( msg )>=0){
 console.log("YES");
} else {
 console.log("NO");
}

};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="index.js"></script>
<div>
 <p class="user" id="user">User: </p>
 <p class="bot" id="bot">Bot: </p>
</div>
<input class="talk" id="msg" placeholder="Start Talking!"></input><button class="send" onclick="send()">Send</button>
<p>Once Finished Type Finished.</p>
<p>Enter Some Greetings.</p>
<input placeholder="Enter Here, Friend!" id="greets"></input>
<button onclick="greets()">Enter Greet</button>
<br>
<p>Enter Some Question You Would Normally Ask.</p>
<input placeholder="Enter Here, Friend!" id="ques"></input>
<button onclick="ques()">Enter question</button>
<br>
<p>Enter Some Responses.</p>
<input placeholder="Enter Here, Friend!" id="res"></input>
<button onclick="res()">Enter Responses</button>
<br />
<style>
.talk{
 float: right;
 width: 750px;
}
div{
 border: 1px solid black;
 float: right;
 width: 800px;
 height: 250px;
}
.send{
 float:right;
 background-color: lightblue;
 border-radius: 2px;
 border: 2px solid black

}
</style>


<button onclick="loadgreets()">Load Files</button>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to make 2 changes:

First, `var msg = document.getElementById("msg")` should be `var msg = document.getElementById("msg").value` to get the value of the input, not the element itself

Second, `if(types.indexOf( msg )>=0)` would work if msg was an exact match to one of the objects in `types`. However, because `types` is an array of objects, and it looks like you want to match the `key`, you can do something like what's suggested in this question: [Find a value in an array of objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462318/find-a-value-in-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

```
function contains(msg, types){
    for (var i=0; i < types.length; i++) {
        if (types[i].key === msg) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

if(contains(msg, types){
    console.log("YES");
} else {
    console.log("NO");
}
```

Comment: you need to change the clause if(types[i].key === "greet") and then make another loop over types[i].data array to match the entered greeting or refactor the types - use key as key ;)

Answer (score 0):

not sure what are you going to do, but maybe I will help you with this advices:

to get the msg value use `document.getElementById("msg")`**.value**;

to check if greeting exists you should use:

```
for(var key in greet) {
    if(greet[key] == msg) {
        //do a response
        break; //no more loops are needed if we found a match
    }
}
```

indexOf is not working on arrays and in javascript is no native function like PHP's in_array.