# set javascript variable to object in array from another variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array and two inputs. I'd like to take the value of the first input and place that in variable. I have that part down. I'd then like to use that variable to find the corresponding array entry and return another object from that array.

The input is `var prodNum=$('input#prodNum').val();`

The array is:

```
var products = [
{
 "brand": "brand1",
 "prodNum": "01-005",
 "YN": "Yes",
 "Stock": "Order"
 },
{
"brand": "brand2",
"prodNum": "02-005",
"YN": "Yes",
"Stock": "Ship"
},
{
"brand": "brand1",
"prodNum": "01-008",
"YN": "No",
"Stock": "Order"
}
]
```

I'd like to return the `"YN"` value to `var YNvalue`, given a certain `prodNum`

For example if `prodNum` = `01-008` , `YNvalue` would be `"No"`

Comment: What have you tried? This is almost the same as [Find a value in an array of objects in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12462318/4642212). The next step is trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to loop over the objects in the `product` array until you find the one that matches:

```js
function getProductYN(productList, productNumber) {
  for (var prodIdx = 0, prodCnt = productList.length; prodIdx < prodCnt; prodIdx++) {
    if (productList[prodIdx].prodNum === productNumber)
      return productList[prodIdx].YN;
  }
}

var products = [{
    "brand": "brand1",
    "prodNum": "01-005",
    "YN": "Yes",
    "Stock": "Order"
  },
  {
    "brand": "brand2",
    "prodNum": "02-005",
    "YN": "Yes",
    "Stock": "Ship"
  },
  {
    "brand": "brand1",
    "prodNum": "01-008",
    "YN": "No",
    "Stock": "Order"
  }
];

var prodNum = "01-008"; // $('input#prodNum').val();
var productYN = getProductYN(products, prodNum);

console.log(productYN);
```

Comment: thank you for the elegant answer, no I just need to break it all down and understand. Much obliged

Answer (score 1):

You could do that by using `find` on the `products` array

```
products.find(product => product.prodNum === prodNum).YN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code. But next time before asking give a try.

```
  var YNvalue;
    for (var index = 0; index < products.length; index++) {
        if (products[index].prodNum === prodNum ) {
            YNvalue = products[index].YN;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I did try, I've been trying for two days. Posting a question on here is always my last resort because I try to learn/figure it out on my own. I didn't want to put up the 30 or so combinations I've tried and didn't get the results I wanted. I appreciate your help, but don't assume people asking the question didn't try.

Comment: @mcadamsjustin Please don't mind. I said as it's looking easy question.

Comment: what's easy for you, isn't easy for everyone. Some of are still learning and arrays confuse me like nothing else

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the YN value of a specific object using their YN number, in this example you could simply loop through each object until you find one that has a matching product number. once we find that object we should return its YN value

```js
var YNvalue = "";
var products = [
{
 "brand": "brand1",
 "prodNum": "01-005",
 "YN": "Yes",
 "Stock": "Order"
 },
{
"brand": "brand2",
"prodNum": "02-005",
"YN": "Yes",
"Stock": "Ship"
},
{
"brand": "brand1",
"prodNum": "01-008",
"YN": "No",
"Stock": "Order"
}
]
function main() {
  var option = window.prompt("Product Number?", "01-008")
  YNvalue = getYNByProdNum(option)
  window.alert("Your YN value is simply " + YNvalue)
  console.log(YNvalue);
}

function getYNByProdNum(prodNum) {
  //loop through each product until we find on number that matches
  for(i in products) {
    //if product's number matches we return the YN value
    if(products[i].prodNum == prodNum) {
      return products[i].YN
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="main()">
<div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

whoopsie, a little slow I am