# Search array for specific string and return the value to AngularJS view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

In the code below, I'm trying to search the JSON output for a specific string (for example 'name_col_lbl') and return its value (in this case 'Name') for AngularJS to ouptut in the view.

```
$scope.globalContent = [
    {"id":"1","module":"student_reg","item":"name_col_lbl","value":"Name"},
    {"id":"2","module":"student_reg","item":"bday_col_lbl","value":"Birthdate"}
]
angular.forEach($scope.globalContent, function(el){
    $scope.nameLbl = el ***This is where I need to search for the string and return its value***;
    $scope.bdayLbl= el ***This is where I need to search for the string and return its value***;

});
```

I can't seem to find an efficient way to handle this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```js
var $scopeglobalContent = [
    {"id":"1","module":"student_reg","item":"name_col_lbl","value":"Name"},
    {"id":"2","module":"student_reg","item":"bday_col_lbl","value":"Birthdate"}
];

for(var i = 0; i < $scopeglobalContent.length; i++){
 for(key in $scopeglobalContent[i]){
   if($scopeglobalContent[i][key] == "name_col_lbl"){
     return console.log($scopeglobalContent[i].value);
    }
  }
}
```

This is basic stuff. I suggest you read on `objects` and `loops` to get a better understanding of how this works and how to use it.

Comment: Thank you. I'm self-taught and indeed missing some very basic knowledge. I appreciate every learning opportunity.

Comment: @spookybot I'm self-taught too and the way I learned was by reading and writing more code and trying out different concepts and techniques.

Comment: Also, for clarity to anyone who comes across this post, it should $scope.globalContent in your code. with AngularJS you need the period after $scope.

Comment: @spookybot I removed the `$scope.` because I ran it in jsfiddle

Comment: Cool I appreciate the guidance. Reading more about objects and loops now.

Answer (score 0):

From [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462318/find-a-value-in-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript), here's how you can search an array of objects:

```
var obj = array.filter(function ( obj ) {
    return obj.item === "name_col_lbl";
});
```

`obj` will contain either the value of `name_col_lbl` or `undefined` if the key doesn't exist.

So your code would look like this:

```
function findObject(array, keyName) {
    var obj = array.filter(function ( obj ) {
        return obj.item === keyName;
    })[0];
    return obj;
}

$scope.globalContent = [
    {"id":"1","module":"student_reg","item":"name_col_lbl","value":"Name"},
    {"id":"2","module":"student_reg","item":"bday_col_lbl","value":"Birthdate"}
]
angular.forEach($scope.globalContent, function(el){
    $scope.nameLbl = findObject($scope.globalContent, "name_col_lbl")['value]' ***This is where I need to search for the string and return its value***;
    $scope.bdayLbl= findObject($scope.globalContent, "bday_col_lbl")['value]' ***This is where I need to search for the string and return its value***;
});
```

The `findObject` function filters the array by returning the first object that it finds where `obj.item` matches whatever is contained in `keyName`.  This is the `obj` object which gets returned.  Since you don't want the whole object but just a value of that object, I've taken the result of the `findObject($scope.globalContent, "name_col_lbl")` and added `['value']` which will return just the `value` key which is what you want to display in the Angular view.

Comment: I like your approach Dr. Cool

Do you feel this is a more efficient and/or a cleaner way to approach this compared to @Josan_Iracheta answer?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure this accomplishes my goal. This doesn't return the value of the "value" string associated with the object that matches the string.

Comment: I updated the code to pull the "value" string as you needed... try it now. Also, I like Josan's answer.  I think both of these are good, and they're a great way for you to see two different ways to accomplish the same thing.  As for performance, I'm not sure which is faster but you're not searching a huge amount of data (I assume) so I think you'll be fine with either method.

Comment: Thank you very much Dr. Cool -- this is a great learning opportunity for me.

Comment: @Dr.Cool your code will not work in this example because `array` has to be `$scope.globalContent`. Secondly, you're only searching the first object in the array. It would be better if the function would search the array without you having to explicitly declare an index to search in, which is what my code does.

Comment: I just noticed the problem with `array` which I just fixed.  And thanks for pointing out that it's only searching the first element in the array.  I fixed that too.

Comment: @Dr.Cool Also, `array.filter()` returns an array so in this case, I think it would be more suitable to return a string instead.

Comment: I added back in the `[0]` because I realized that it will cause it to return the first value of the array.  The `filter` function will return an array where any array items match the test in the function.  If more than one item matches, we don't want duplicates so I grab only the first one with [0].  Now it's not returning an array, but an object.