# Search values in array of objects js

Tags: javascript, arrays, mutual-exclusion

I need to push my new object in array of objects and check: if new object doesnt overlap objects that exists by start and end values. I write this one. Can i make it shorter? Or maybe there is better method to do it?

```
let arr = [
    {
        start: 0,
        end: 10
    },
    {
        start: 30,
        end: 40
    },
    {
        start: 60,
        end: 70
    },
    {
        start: 100,
        end: 110
    },
    {
        start: 140,
        end: 150
    },
    {
        start: 180,
        end: 190
    }
];

let objToPush = {
    start: 45,
    end: 50
}

if (!arr.find(o => objToPush.start > o.start && objToPush.start < o.end)) {
    if (!arr.find(o => objToPush.end > o.start && objToPush.end < o.end)) {
        console.log('push');
        arr.push(objToPush);
    } else {
        console.log('not push');
    }
} else {
    console.log('not push');
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a value in an array of objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462318/find-a-value-in-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: Generate a lookup table so you won't need to search the whole structure over and over again

Comment: Thanks for solution, but i'm kinda new in js. What do you mean by lookup table? Is it another object?

Comment: @redu, no his code doesnt work.

Comment: @SPHINX so how do you think this helps the OP?? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ashish hit the nail on the head, and that overlap comparison is awesome!

For anyone who needs it fast:

```js
const overlaps = (obj1, obj2) => (
  obj1.start < obj2.end && obj1.end > obj2.start
);

const overlapExists = (arr, newObj) => (
  arr.some(obj => overlaps(obj, newObj))
);
```

This is assuming that:

1. All objects have a `start` value that's less than or equal to their `end` value.
2. Equal values shouldn't count as overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

*plus please check that your logic will not work for 
existing point (10,20) and point to insert (0, 30)*

yes it can be improved

first of all basic improvement

**those two if statements can be combined to one**

`if( *full condition *) //push`

second improvement

**extract that full condition to a function**

```
function overlaps(obj1, obj2) {
  // check overlap
}
```

then use `overlaps` function for `find` function's predicate 
it will be more readable

one more improvement:
**you can make that condition for overlap easier**

let for simplicity two points being compared be (a,b) and (c,d)
*// a,b are start and end of first object and c,d for second*
*assuming a <= b and c <= d*

condition for overlap of two points is

`a < d && b > c`

this is what your `overlaps` function can use

*please try to write code for this one and check if it doesnt work*

Answer (score 0):

If *end* is smaller than the existing *end*, start will be too. The same applies the other way round, so we actually just need one condition:

```
if (!arr.find(o => 
 !( objToPush.end < o.start ||
    objToPush.start > o.end )
)) arr.push(objToPush);
```

---

We can extract that into a function and return false if it fails:

```
const add = objToPush => !arr.find(o => 
 !( objToPush.end < o.start ||
    objToPush.start > o.end )
)) && arr.push(objToPush);

console.log(add({start:5,end:15}));
```

[In action](http://jsbin.com/poxivunula/edit?console)