# how to get value from object with a partial index value javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object which contains alot of keys and values. I can get any value using the index. But I dont have the full index, I have a part of it, would I be able to get the value based on a part of the index.

Example:

```
c = {'select':'MyValue',...}
```

I can get the value using indexing as shown below:

```
c['select'] = 'MyValue'
```

I tried to create this function which searches exact value:

```
function search(nameKey, c){
    for (var i=0; i < c.length; i++) {
        if (c[i].select === nameKey) {
            return c[i];
        }
    }
}
```

`c['select']` will return `'MyValue'` but I need to do something like `c['Sel']` or `c['select']` or `c['Select']`or `c['selected']`to return the same `'MyValue'`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] along with expected results and search criteria

Comment: You'll need to iterate over the object's attributes to find those that match. More than one may be returned. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12462387/751484

Comment: @charlietfl I have provided more details

Comment: @SMH, so what is the matching rule? Is it this? "Regardless of upper/lowercase, if the search string appears in the attribute name, or if the attribute name appears in the search string, then it is a match."

Comment: yes, thats exactly what I want

Comment: @SMH, do you want all possible matches returned, or just the first one encountered?

Comment: It shouldn't have any duplication

Comment: It really doesn't matter if it *shouldn't*. How do you want the function to behave if it *does* have duplication?

Comment: return the first one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the logic doesn't seem to be very clear and it's not quite relevant how it would be matching the `key`.

But This is a function that may help in the specific cases you showed:

```
function search(nameKey, obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(nameKey)) {
    return obj[nameKey];
  } else {
    var res = Object.keys(obj).filter(function(k) {
      return (k.toLowerCase().indexOf(nameKey.toLowerCase()) > -1) || (nameKey.toLowerCase().indexOf(k.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    });
    return res ? obj[res] : false;
  }
}
```

**Explanation:**

- First we use [`Object#hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to check if the object has the searched name as key/property, we return it's value, this will avoid looping all the keys.
- Otherwise we use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the keys of the object.
- Then we use [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method over the `keys` array to check if a relevant `key` exists we
  return it's value, otherwise we return `false`.

**Demo:**

```js
function search(nameKey, obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(nameKey)) {
    return obj[nameKey];
  } else {
    var res = Object.keys(obj).filter(function(k) {
      return (k.toLowerCase().indexOf(nameKey.toLowerCase()) > -1) || (nameKey.toLowerCase().indexOf(k.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    });
    return res ? obj[res] : false;
  }
}
var c = {
  'select': 'MyValue'
};
console.log(search("Sel", c));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an one liner (!):

Assuming your array is in `data` and the partial index value is in `selector`:

```
const result = Object.keys(data).filter(k => k.toLowerCase().indexOf(selector.toLowerCase()) != -1).map(k => data[k]);
```

The above code returns an Array (coz, there may be more than one match). If you just need a first element, just do `result[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys()` to get an array of the property names.

Then find first match using `Array#find()` to get the key needed (if it exists)

```js
const data = {
  aaaa: 1,
  bbbbbbb: 2,
  cccc: 3
}


function search(nameKey, obj) {
  nameKey = nameKey.toLowerCase();// normalize both to lowercase to make it case insensitive
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  const wantedKey = keys.find(key => key.toLowerCase().includes(nameKey));
  return wantedKey ? obj[wantedKey] : false;
}

console.log('Term "a" value:', search('a',data))
console.log('Term "bb" value:', search('bb',data))
console.log('Term "X" value:', search('X',data))
```

Since search criteria is vague I simply found any match anywhere in the property name and didn't look past the first one found

Comment: OP has also asked (in the comments) for a match to be true if the attribute name appears in any part of the search string. If you add that, I think you've got a solution here.

Comment: Thank you, but It says expecting newline or semicolon on this line: const wantedKey = keys.find(key => key.toLowerCase().includes(nameKey));

Comment: @JonathanM `includes()` is not index specific. The match is being made anywhere in the key

Comment: @SMH it might be that your environment is not set up to use arrow functions. Can chnge to `keys.find(function(key)( return  key.toLowerCase().includes(nameKey)});`

Comment: Create a working demo that reproduces problem in jsfiddle.net or other sandbox site