# Search in and return a json object in JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a JSON object with user information, its a large array of thousand of users an example of one is:

```
[ { 
    "FirstName" : "Joe",
    "LastName" : "Doe",
    "Address" : "123 Main Street"
   }
]
```

I want to be able to search in this json array based on first and last name and return the object that matches.

Comment: Then iterate over that array and find that one that matches? Which problem do you have?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a value in an array of objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462318/find-a-value-in-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse json and use Array.prototype.find:

```
const arr = JSON.parse("your json")

const result = arr.find(elem => elem.FirstName === "Joe")
```

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [es6-feature](http://es6-features.org/#ArrayElementFinding)

There're 2 method in array:

- find:  `array.find(x => x.firstName === 'Joe' && x.LastName === 'Doe' )`: returns single matche which means exactly 1 object or null.
- filter: `array.filter(x => x.firstName === 'Joe' && x.LastName === 'Doe' )` returns array of matches.

Comment: Because of `x.firstName = 'Joe'` everybody will be called Joe X afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the filter function on array

```
var result = largeJsonArray.filter(function(item){
   return item.FirstName === 'Jhon' && item.LastName === 'Doe'
});
```

result is a list of element that match the criteria

take a look to the documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: var foundItem = userData.filter(user => {
            return user.FirstName === userParts[0] &&
            user.LastName === userParts[1];
          }); I am getting error 'filter is not a function'

Comment: filter only exists on javascript arrays, check if userData is an array