# Search in json file with Node JS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have several objects like this and wonder how I can search between these, say that we got the number 1 and want to figure out what the name is. 
Should I loop it or what do you guys suggest?

To make things clear, I do want to get the other objects by using the number. Is it possible?

```
    {
      "room": [
          {
              "number": "1",
              "name": "room1"
          },
          {
              "number": "2",
              "name": "room2"
          }
      ]
   }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a value in an array of objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462318/find-a-value-in-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a map and use the room number as identifier. This way you can access the room data via the room number like that:

```js
var data = {
    "room": [
        {
            "number": "1",
            "name": "room1"
        },
        {
            "number": "2",
            "name": "room2"
        }
    ]
};
// or load it from a file:
// var data = require('./data.json');
   
var rooms = new Map();
for(room of data.room) {
    rooms.set(Number(room.number), room);
}
// access data for room with number 1
alert(rooms.get(1).name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, bring in the file. Make sure to include the './' before the file name to show that it's from the current directory.

```
const data = require('./data.json');
```

Now the JSON data is stored inside the variable `data`. To access the members, use the dot operator. `data.room` will return the array of rooms.

To access the individual room, use `data.room[i]` where `i` is the numbered element in the array (starting from 0). For example, to access the first room:

```
const first_room = data.room[0];
```

This `first_room` variable can now be used to access the name.

```
console.log(first_room.name);
```

This will log "room1" to the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. This will help you.

```js
var roomData =  {
      "room": [
          {
              "number": "1",
              "name": "room1"
          },
          {
              "number": "2",
              "name": "room2"
          }
      ]
   }
   
for(key in roomData.room){
  console.log("Room Number - " + roomData.room[key].number);
  console.log("Room Name - " + roomData.room[key].name);
}
```