# How to reference an Object based on a Key Value?

Tags: oop, object, variables, properties, key

I have an array of objects: `[obj1, obj2, obj3]`

```
obj1 = {id:1,name:First}
obj2 = {id:2,name:Second}
...
```

But the object's array indexes are constantly changing. How else can I reference a specific object given only its *id property*? The goal is to set a variable equal to the name property (e.g. obj1's name = First). In other words, how can I reference an object's property given the key to a different property?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Can you give us more details about the programming language you are using?

Comment: Using Mocha, Chai, supertest, and JavaScript to test API endpoints. Trying to write a unit-test for a delete endpoint. But to do that, I need to get an object's *name* using only its *id* number from the response body containing the array of objects.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question, but have you tried to use a Map data structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is multiple ways to achieve this, it only depends on performance requirement. Here's a Stack Overflow thread that I think solve your question:

[Find a value in an array of objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462318/find-a-value-in-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

I am also adding my favorite solution here:

**ES6** `Array.prototype.find` function

```
var id = 1;
var arr = [{...},...];
var obj = arr.find(o => o.id === id);
```