# The double for-loop do not get the return data

Tags: javascript

Why my code is not `count`?

```
var a = {
  count: [{label:'a', value: 'a'}],
  next: [{label:'b', value: 'b'}],
  previous: [{label:'c', value: 'c'}],
}

function get_item() {

  var x = "a"

  for (let item in a){
    a[item].forEach(obj => {
      console.log(obj.value, x )   
      if(obj.value === x) {
        return item
      }
    })
  }
}


console.log(get_item())
```

the console logs are bellow:

```
a a
b a
c a
undefined
```

you see the `a a`, but why it do not is the `count` rather than `undefined`?

Comment: what is the expected count value?

Comment: `forEach` does not return anything. So any return value is not respected. Use `.find` or `.filter`

Comment: return a[item].forEach

Comment: Do you want that Once this condition "if(obj.value === x) {" true it returns not executing before?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a value in an array of objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462318/find-a-value-in-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below solution may work for you:

```
 var a = {
        count: [{label:'a', value: 'a'}],
        next: [{label:'b', value: 'b'}],
        previous: [{label:'c', value: 'c'}]
       }
    function get_item() {
           var x = "a"
           for (let item in a){
            let resultItem = a[item].find((obj)=>{ return obj.value === x });
            if(resultItem) return item //you can also return 'resultItem';
            }
          }
          console.log(get_item())
```

Answer (score 0):

change your function as such.

```js
var a = {
  count: [{label:'a', value: 'a'}],
  next: [{label:'b', value: 'b'}],
  previous: [{label:'c', value: 'c'}],
}

function get_item() {

  var x = "w"
  var retItem = undefined
  for (let item in a){
    a[item].forEach(obj => {  
      if(obj.value === x) {
        retItem = item
      }
    })
  }
  return retItem;
}


console.log(get_item())
```

Here we just assign the result into a variable `retItem`. If we find something we return it, or we just return undefined

Comment: Just a pointer, `get_item` should return `object | undefined`. Returning `" No result ..."` should be handled by function consuming it.