# How to validate if my list consist of same name and alert already exist?

Tags: reactjs

I want to validate the name if it's already exit or not.

if Exist there should be a pop up to change the name

Here is my list of object before saving.

[image]

input change

```
handleStoryboardTitleChange = (e) => {
this.setState({ storyboardTitle: e.target.value });
};
```

save function

handleSaveButton = () => {
};

How to check if boardTitle is already exit , if exit need popup,later it should not execute flow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a value in an array of objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462318/find-a-value-in-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: @HaydenCarlson i need help in react as well, is this a duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually use this

```
var index = boardTitlesList.findIndex((item) => {
    return item.boardTitle === SEARCHED_TITLE
});

if (index === -1) {
    /* NOT FOUND */
} else {
    /* FOUND */
}
```

[image: Edit m54vl37p08]

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) you may found polyfill for `findIndex`

Comment: Where do we get  SEARCHED_TITLE

Comment: this is your e.target.value

Comment: can i put it directly e.target.value?? because it is inside the the other function

Comment: or it should be this.state.target value??

Comment: is this  should be inside handleStoryboardTitleChange() or handleSaveButton()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172442/discussion-between-sasha-kos-and-jmr).

Comment: return item.boardTitle === SEARCHED_TITLE ----->it returns 1            so condition fails

Comment: Thanks you for you valuable time , it helped me a lot