# Efficient way to get object from array based on key

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects as:

```
  0: {id: "1", name: "Tab1", address: "123 Street"}
  1: {id: "2", name: "Tab2", address: "456 Avenue"}
  2: {id: "3", name: "Tab3", address: "789 st"}
```

I want to grab a particular object from the above array based on the "name" key. For example, if I pass the key as "Tab1" it should return me:

```
0: {id: "1", name: "Tab1", address: "123 Street"}
```

I can loop through the array and get the values but wanted to know is there any simpler/efficient way to get the desired data.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that array index 0 has "Tab1", 1 has "Tab2", and so on? Is the data replaced frequently, or could the construction of an index structure be feasible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462318/find-a-value-in-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964155/get-javascript-object-from-array-of-objects-by-value-of-property

Comment: @NenadVracar Thanks for the inputs.

Comment: Sorry guys I always search first before posting. Looks like this time my search keywords were not good. Will keep this in minding before posting.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) like this

```
const searchArray = key => array.find(({name})=> {
    return name === key;
});

console.log(searchArray("Tab1"));
```

Comment: By answering this question, you are engorging users not to do an research by they ask, it is clear that this question shows no research efforts of any kind