# Map through array of objects and filter out array by property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have a question whats the best way to filter the object that has an array of objects and i would like to return an object that has the matching property

```
const test = Object.keys(repo).map((keyName, i) => {
   if(repo[keyName].name === post_name) {
     console.log(repo[keyName])
   } 
})
```

the code above works but i feel like its not a best way to achieve it maybe someone has a better way of solving this.

Comment: how does the code works for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a value in an array of objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462318/find-a-value-in-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to filter an existing array and create a new array, you should use `.filter`. Only use `.map` when you're creating another array from every element in an existing array - don't use it for side effects.

You can use `Object.values` instead of `Object.keys`, since it looks like you only care about the values:

```
const test = Object.values(repo).filter(({ name }) => name === post_name);
```

Then you'll have an array of the objects with a matching `name`.

If you know that there's only going to be one matching object, use `.find` instead:

```
const match = Object.values(repo).find(({ name }) => name === post_name);
```