# React-multi-select-dropdown

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Trying to populate an array of options for  React-multi-select-dropdown

```
   this.state.users.map((user) => {
      if (!this.state.options.includes(user.badgeId))
        this.state.options.push({ name: user.badgeId, id: user._id });
      return this.state.options;
    });
```

getting multiple values of the same in the options array.

```
    <Multiselect
      options={this.state.options} // Options to display in the dropdown
      //isObject={false}
      onSelect={this.onSelect} // Function will trigger on select event
      // onRemove={this.onRemove} // Function will trigger on remove event
      displayValue='name' // Property name to display in the dropdown options
    />
```

also once selected and form submitted the selected user.badgeId will need to be in its own array.

Answer (score 1):

The issue: your code checks if the value `user.badgeId` is **not** in the array `options`. Which always returns true because such array is populated with objects like: `{ name: user.badgeId, id: user._id }`

A simple example:

```
const myArray = [{a: 1, b:'banana'}, {a: 2, b:'banana'}]

myArray.includes(1) // false
```

Instead you can use [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get a object in the array which has `name === badgeId`.

find() returns the value of the first element that satisfies the provided test function. This will be `undefined` if nothing is found.

Now we can search for and element in the array and do something if we find it. Like this:

```
const findResult = this.state.options.find((obj) => obj.name === user.badgeId);
if (typeof findResult === "undefined")
  // Do something
```

I'm not very good with the words so feel free to ask for clarification if this is confusing. Or you can see if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12462414/9952961) helps

Answer (score 0):

```
const b = this.state.users.map((obj, index) => ({
  name: obj.username,
  id: obj.badgeId,
}));
```