# How to find if specific key with value exist in array jQuery?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an array and I need to find if it contains specific value using jQuery

```
var my_array = [
      {"Order":{"id":"93","company_name":"name1"}},
      {"Order":{"id":"98","company_name":"name2"}},
      {"Order":{"id":"30","company_name":"name3"}},
      {"Order":{"id":"3","company_name":"name4"}},
      {"Order":{"id":"13","company_name":"name5"}}
]
```

I want to know if this array has id:3.
I tried this:

```
if(jQuery.inArray(id, my_array) !== -1) {
   console.log("is in array");
 } else {
   console.log("is NOT in array");
 }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I change a bit question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462318/find-a-value-in-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check whether it contains your desired value without iterating the whole array, then use pure JavaScript `some` method.

As [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) says:

> The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array
> passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a
> Boolean value.

An example:

```js
let my_array = [
      {"Order":{"id":"93","company_name":"name1"}},
      {"Order":{"id":"98","company_name":"name2"}},
      {"Order":{"id":"30","company_name":"name3"}},
      {"Order":{"id":"3","company_name":"name4"}},
      {"Order":{"id":"13","company_name":"name5"}}
]

let found = my_array.some(f => f.Order.id == 3);
console.log(`contains`, found)
```

In addition, it is possible to use pure JavaScript method called `find` method, however, be careful [it returns the first item found by your condition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), not all items. If you want to find all items, then use `filter` method with the same condition:

```js
let my_array = [
      {"Order":{"id":"93","company_name":"name1"}},
      {"Order":{"id":"98","company_name":"name2"}},
      {"Order":{"id":"30","company_name":"name3"}},
      {"Order":{"id":"3","company_name":"name4"}},
      {"Order":{"id":"13","company_name":"name5"}}
]

let found = my_array.find(f => f.Order.id == 3);
console.log(found)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this by filtering the array. Filter by the inner object's ID and check the length of the returned array. If it's 1 or greater, it contains the object you're searching for.

```js
var my_array = [
      {"Order":{"id":"93","company_name":"name1"}},
      {"Order":{"id":"98","company_name":"name2"}},
      {"Order":{"id":"30","company_name":"name3"}},
      {"Order":{"id":"3","company_name":"name4"}},
      {"Order":{"id":"13","company_name":"name5"}}
];

var valueToCheck = 3;
console.log(my_array.filter(x => {return x.Order.id == valueToCheck;}).length > 0);
```

Here it is as a function:

```js
var my_array = [
      {"Order":{"id":"93","company_name":"name1"}},
      {"Order":{"id":"98","company_name":"name2"}},
      {"Order":{"id":"30","company_name":"name3"}},
      {"Order":{"id":"3","company_name":"name4"}},
      {"Order":{"id":"13","company_name":"name5"}}
];


function checkArray(array, value)
{
  return array.filter(x => {return x.Order.id == value;}).length > 0;
}

console.log(checkArray(my_array, 3));
console.log(checkArray(my_array, 4));
```