# How to find an attribute value in an array of objects that are each an array of objects that is coming from an API response

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, data-structures

Say I have the following array of unnamed objects each of which is an array of named objects:

```
[{id: 123, name: 'Foo', code: 'ABC123', enabled: true},{id: 124, name: 'Bar', code: '123ABC', enabled: true}]
```

This data has been converted into an Array of objects from a API call response, so none of the named objects are defined. For instance I cant check the `name` of any object using something like:

```
for (let i = 0; i < resp.length; i++){
    if(resp[i].name = key){do something}
}
```

(i.e the solution for the following question: [Find a value in an array of objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462318/find-a-value-in-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)) because `name` is undefined for the objects in resp.

Is there a way for me to access that attribute on that object?

Answer (score 0):

I would just use what your code, but slightly changed. The main error is that you're assigning a variable in your if statement (=) instead of comparing (==).

You also need to add a key and a matching word to the value of that key: `resp[i][key] == match`

```js
const apiResponseArr = [{id: 123, name: 'Foo', code: 'ABC123', enabled: true},{id: 124, name: 'Bar', code: '123ABC', enabled: true}];


function find(resp, match, key) {
  key = key || 'name';
  
  for (let i = 0; i < resp.length; i++){
    if(resp[i][key] == match) { return resp[i]; }
  }

  return 'not found';
}

console.log( find(apiResponseArr, 'Bar') ); // [object]
console.log( find(apiResponseArr, 'Zzz') ); // 'not found'

console.log( find(apiResponseArr, 'ABC123', 'code') ); // [object]
```

In your linked thread, [you got a suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38500417/5526624) of writing it in an even shorter way:

```js
const apiResponseArr = [{id: 123, name: 'Foo', code: 'ABC123', enabled: true},{id: 124, name: 'Bar', code: '123ABC', enabled: true}];


function find(resp, match, key = 'name') {
  return resp.find(x => x[key] === match);
}

console.log( find(apiResponseArr, 'Bar') ); // [object]
console.log( find(apiResponseArr, 'Zzz') ); // undefined

console.log( find(apiResponseArr, 'ABC123', 'code') ); // [object]
```