# searching and looping in an array using javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I have an array that looks like this:

```
[{"id":23,"site_id":13, "name":"Test 1","date":"2019-01-26T11:02:18.5661283","category":"some cats"},
{"id":151,"site_id":15, "name":"Test 2","date":"2018-11-04T10:50:53.1756567","category":"some cats"}]
```

I need to search by site_id in this array and display the found ones:

so I did something like this which doesn't work:

```
var siteID = 13;

$.each(myArray.filter(
            function (el) { 
               return el.site_id !== siteID ;
            }), 
            function( index, value ) {

                var fo = '<p>'+el.name+'</p>';
                $('.forms').append(fo);

            });
```

Can someone please advice on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find a value in an array of objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462318/find-a-value-in-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: Please return and interact with the people who spent time helping you

Answer (score 2):

You can simply loop through the data to perform this task.

Consider the following code:-

You can add break statement if you're sure that the site_id is unique in object in the data.

```js
let siteId = 13;
let dataRows = [
    {"id":23,"site_id":13, "name":"Test 1","date":"2019-01-26T11:02:18.5661283","category":"some cats"},
    {"id":151,"site_id":15, "name":"Test 2","date":"2018-11-04T10:50:53.1756567","category":"some cats"}  
];

let formElements = '';

for(let data of dataRows){
  if(data.site_id == siteId){
    formElements += '<p>'+data.name+'</p>';
  }
}
$('.forms').append(formElements);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="forms"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the `Array.filter()` as below -

```
filteredArray = myArray.filter((a)=> {return a.site_id === siteID})
```

Here, we are calling `.filter()` on `myArray` and if the condition inside the function stays true, that element is returned otherwise it is dropped.

Outputs as -

```
Object { id: 23, site_id: 13, name: "Test 1", … }
```

since only this element's `site_id` matched the one provided.

Comment: OP had `!== siteID`

Comment: True. Anyways, the purpose was to explain the way. Also, the question body mentions `search by site_id` so I would guess OP wanted to filter out the one matching. :)

Answer (score 2):

Simpler to filter and then map. We want to update the DOM in one go

```js
const arr = [{"id":23,"site_id":13, "name":"Test 1","date":"2019-01-26T11:02:18.5661283","category":"some cats"},
{"id":151,"site_id":15, "name":"Test 2","date":"2018-11-04T10:50:53.1756567","category":"some cats"}]

const mySiteId = 13;
$('.forms').append(
  arr
  .filter(({site_id}) => site_id !== mySiteId)
  .map(({name}) => `<p>${name}</p>`).join("")
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="forms"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to do for loop/map
like this :

the array:

```
var arr = [
    {"id":23,"site_id":13, "name":"Test 1","date":"2019-01-26T11:02:18.5661283","category":"some cats"},
    {"id":151,"site_id":15, "name":"Test 2","date":"2018-11-04T10:50:53.1756567","category":"some cats"}  
];
```

for loop:

```
for (let e of arr){
  if(e.site_id == 15){
    //do something
  }
}
```

you can also do a switch-case for it

```
for (let e of arr){
  switch(e.site_id){
    case 15 {
      //do something if the id is 15 
    }
    case 13{
      //do something if the id is 13 
    }
    case 99 {
      //do something if the id is 99
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just simply loop through the given list  and then match  using Ngif
The following is an example of using JavaScript to loop through an array.

```
let myArray = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];

     for(let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){ 
     console.log(myArray[i]);
}
```