# Find nested list in array by key value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

Suppose I have an array of nested objects:

```
 this_menu = [{food_name: 'hamburger', food_attr: ['big', 'yummy', 'cheap']}, {food_name: 'sushi', food_attr: ['healthy', 'expensive', 'yummy']}, {food_name: 'tacos', food_attr: ['yummy', 'cheap', 'small']}]
```

If I want to find the the nested object that contains 'sushi', I could simply call `this_array[1]` by index. But lets say, I want to find it strictly by the key - food_name's value. I want to do this without using a for loop if possible and in a single line if it can be done. I basically want to return the object: `{food_name: 'sushi', food_attr: ['healthy', 'expensive', 'yummy']}`. I tried the following, but I think the syntax is wrong (throws a syntax error). Any suggestions on getting this to work:

```
tonights_dinner = this_menu.map((x) => if(x.food_name == `sushi') { return x});
```

Comment: you can use find. but even with find it uses a loop anyway. `this_menu.find(({food_name}) => food_name==='sushi')`         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462318/find-a-value-in-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Comment: btw the map also does a loop

Comment: Q: why is it necessary to be all on one line?

Comment: Yeah, find looks like a viable solution. In regards to the loop, what I wanted to avoid was a multi-liner `for` loop; sorry should have been more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### If you are sure there will be exactly one hit, use `.find()`

This might be the case if you know the "sushi" text has actually been picked off that menu itself, and you have pre-arranged for there to be no duplicate food_names.

```js
const this_menu = [{
  food_name: 'hamburger',
  food_attr: ['big', 'yummy', 'cheap']
}, {
  food_name: 'sushi',
  food_attr: ['healthy', 'expensive', 'yummy']
}, {
  food_name: 'tacos',
  food_attr: ['yummy', 'cheap', 'small']
}]

const result = this_menu.find(item => item.food_name === "sushi")

console.log(result)
```

#### If you are unsure whether there will be 0, 1 or more hits, use `.filter()`

This is a more general situation. In this case you will want to know the number of hits, as well as have a list of hits.

```js
const this_menu = [{
  food_name: 'hamburger',
  food_attr: ['big', 'yummy', 'cheap']
}, {
  food_name: 'sushi',
  food_attr: ['healthy', 'expensive', 'yummy']
}, {
  food_name: 'tacos',
  food_attr: ['yummy', 'cheap', 'small']
}]

const results = this_menu.filter(item => item.food_name === "sushi")

console.log(results.length)
console.log(results)
```