# get a value from an object matching another value

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json that is like the following:

```
[
    {"id":1,"nome":"smartform","url":"smartform.php","label":"Dashboard","icon":"fas fa-th-large","data_attribute":"","parent":"Smartform"},
    {"id":2,"nome":"form_wizard","url":"form_wizard.php","label":"Crea uno Smartform","icon":"fas fa-plus","data_attribute":"data-action=\"create\" data-step=\"0\" data-token=\"0\"","parent":"Smartform"},
    {"id":3,"nome":"fullcalendar","url":"fullcalendar.php","label":"Calendario","icon":"far fa-calendar","data_attribute":"","parent":"Tools"},
    {"id":4,"nome":"gantt","url":"gantt.php","label":"Gantt","icon":"fas fa-stream","data_attribute":"","parent":"Tools"},
    {"id":5,"nome":"timesheet","url":"timesheet.php","label":"Timesheet","icon":"fas fa-hourglass","data_attribute":"","parent":"Tools"},
    {"id":6,"nome":"kanban","url":"kanban.php","label":"Kanban","icon":"fas fa-list-ul","data_attribute":"","parent":"Tools"},
    {"id":7,"nome":"openpoints","url":"items.php?tipo=openpoints","label":"Open Points","icon":"fas fa-keyboard","data_attribute":"","parent":"Risk Management"},
    {"id":8,"nome":"risks","url":"items.php?tipo=risks","label":"Rischi","icon":"fas fa-exclamation","data_attribute":"","parent":"Risk Management"},
    {"id":9,"nome":"issues","url":"items.php?tipo=issues","label":"Issue","icon":"fas fa-fire","data_attribute":"","parent":"Risk Management"},
    {"id":10,"nome":"changerequests","url":"items.php?tipo=changerequests","label":"Change Requests","icon":"fas fa-plus","data_attribute":"","parent":"Risk Management"}
]
```

I currently parse it with `JSON.parse` and use it efficiently. What I'd like to do now is the following.
I have a variable whose value is "fullcalendar" (can be any of the "nome" in the json). I want to look for that in the array and return "fullcalendar.php" that is the value of another property of this object.

How do I do it? I am trying to understand if I can do it with `filter` but don't see how to implement it. Any suggestion?

Comment: If you're looking for a single element use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and grab whatever property/properties you need out of the returned object. It's not clear what specific issue you're having.

Comment: Please show your attempts. there are tons of questions like this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find a value in an array of objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462318/find-a-value-in-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `find()` method instead of `filter()` to find the object with a specific value for the "nome" property in your JSON array. Here's an example:

```
const jsonArray = [
    // Your JSON array here...
];

const searchTerm = "fullcalendar";
const foundObject = jsonArray.find(obj => obj.nome === searchTerm);

if (foundObject) {
    const url = foundObject.url;
    console.log(url); // "fullcalendar.php"
} else {
    console.log("Object not found in the array.");
}
```

In this example, the `find()` method is used to search for the first object in the `jsonArray` that has a "nome" property equal to the `searchTerm`. If a matching object is found, the value of its "url" property is returned. Otherwise, a message indicating that the object was not found is logged.

Using `find()` is a more efficient choice than filter() in this case because it stops searching as soon as the first matching object is found, rather than iterating over the entire array.

Comment: thanks. It is ok that it stops at the first match (it is the only one) and it is not necessary to have a fallback for not finding (it is not possible). Also, your code has all the other properties in foundObject and that's a good point too

Comment: Most or all of your six answers here appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues. m

Answer (score 1):

Use `.find` method to return the object with `fullcalendar` value in it then print only the `url` property

```js
const arr = [
    {"id":1,"nome":"smartform","url":"smartform.php","label":"Dashboard","icon":"fas fa-th-large","data_attribute":"","parent":"Smartform"},
    {"id":2,"nome":"form_wizard","url":"form_wizard.php","label":"Crea uno Smartform","icon":"fas fa-plus","data_attribute":"data-action=\"create\" data-step=\"0\" data-token=\"0\"","parent":"Smartform"},
    {"id":3,"nome":"fullcalendar","url":"fullcalendar.php","label":"Calendario","icon":"far fa-calendar","data_attribute":"","parent":"Tools"},
    {"id":4,"nome":"gantt","url":"gantt.php","label":"Gantt","icon":"fas fa-stream","data_attribute":"","parent":"Tools"},
    {"id":5,"nome":"timesheet","url":"timesheet.php","label":"Timesheet","icon":"fas fa-hourglass","data_attribute":"","parent":"Tools"},
    {"id":6,"nome":"kanban","url":"kanban.php","label":"Kanban","icon":"fas fa-list-ul","data_attribute":"","parent":"Tools"},
    {"id":7,"nome":"openpoints","url":"items.php?tipo=openpoints","label":"Open Points","icon":"fas fa-keyboard","data_attribute":"","parent":"Risk Management"},
    {"id":8,"nome":"risks","url":"items.php?tipo=risks","label":"Rischi","icon":"fas fa-exclamation","data_attribute":"","parent":"Risk Management"},
    {"id":9,"nome":"issues","url":"items.php?tipo=issues","label":"Issue","icon":"fas fa-fire","data_attribute":"","parent":"Risk Management"},
    {"id":10,"nome":"changerequests","url":"items.php?tipo=changerequests","label":"Change Requests","icon":"fas fa-plus","data_attribute":"","parent":"Risk Management"}
];

const result = arr.find(x => x.nome == "fullcalendar")
console.log(result.url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
const items = [
    {"id":1,"nome":"smartform","url":"smartform.php","label":"Dashboard","icon":"fas fa-th-large","data_attribute":"","parent":"Smartform"},
    {"id":2,"nome":"form_wizard","url":"form_wizard.php","label":"Crea uno Smartform","icon":"fas fa-plus","data_attribute":"data-action=\"create\" data-step=\"0\" data-token=\"0\"","parent":"Smartform"},
    {"id":3,"nome":"fullcalendar","url":"fullcalendar.php","label":"Calendario","icon":"far fa-calendar","data_attribute":"","parent":"Tools"},
    {"id":4,"nome":"gantt","url":"gantt.php","label":"Gantt","icon":"fas fa-stream","data_attribute":"","parent":"Tools"},
    {"id":5,"nome":"timesheet","url":"timesheet.php","label":"Timesheet","icon":"fas fa-hourglass","data_attribute":"","parent":"Tools"},
    {"id":6,"nome":"kanban","url":"kanban.php","label":"Kanban","icon":"fas fa-list-ul","data_attribute":"","parent":"Tools"},
    {"id":7,"nome":"openpoints","url":"items.php?tipo=openpoints","label":"Open Points","icon":"fas fa-keyboard","data_attribute":"","parent":"Risk Management"},
    {"id":8,"nome":"risks","url":"items.php?tipo=risks","label":"Rischi","icon":"fas fa-exclamation","data_attribute":"","parent":"Risk Management"},
    {"id":9,"nome":"issues","url":"items.php?tipo=issues","label":"Issue","icon":"fas fa-fire","data_attribute":"","parent":"Risk Management"},
    {"id":10,"nome":"changerequests","url":"items.php?tipo=changerequests","label":"Change Requests","icon":"fas fa-plus","data_attribute":"","parent":"Risk Management"}
];

function getUrl(nome) {
  return items.find(item => item.nome === nome)?.url;
}

// more flexible option
function getProperty(searchKey, searchValue, returnKey) {
  const item = items.find(item => item[searchKey] === searchValue);
  return item ? item[returnKey] : item;
}

console.log(getUrl('fullcalendar'));
console.log(getProperty('nome', 'fullcalendar', 'url'));
```

Answer (score 0):

While you could access an individual item using find (or filter), it requires iterating over the array each time.  It sounds like you want arbitrary access to an item by a string key, which is essentially a map/dict.  In this case, I would suggest converting from an array of items to a map of the same items keyed by the 'nome' value.  Then you could access it directly, and more efficiently since random access to a key is constant time.  This would work better assuming you are accessing different values at different time throughout the life of your page/application.

```js
const items = [{
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "smartform",
    "url": "smartform.php",
    "label": "Dashboard",
    "icon": "fas fa-th-large",
    "data_attribute": "",
    "parent": "Smartform"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "nome": "form_wizard",
    "url": "form_wizard.php",
    "label": "Crea uno Smartform",
    "icon": "fas fa-plus",
    "data_attribute": "data-action=\"create\" data-step=\"0\" data-token=\"0\"",
    "parent": "Smartform"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "nome": "fullcalendar",
    "url": "fullcalendar.php",
    "label": "Calendario",
    "icon": "far fa-calendar",
    "data_attribute": "",
    "parent": "Tools"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "nome": "gantt",
    "url": "gantt.php",
    "label": "Gantt",
    "icon": "fas fa-stream",
    "data_attribute": "",
    "parent": "Tools"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "nome": "timesheet",
    "url": "timesheet.php",
    "label": "Timesheet",
    "icon": "fas fa-hourglass",
    "data_attribute": "",
    "parent": "Tools"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "nome": "kanban",
    "url": "kanban.php",
    "label": "Kanban",
    "icon": "fas fa-list-ul",
    "data_attribute": "",
    "parent": "Tools"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "nome": "openpoints",
    "url": "items.php?tipo=openpoints",
    "label": "Open Points",
    "icon": "fas fa-keyboard",
    "data_attribute": "",
    "parent": "Risk Management"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "nome": "risks",
    "url": "items.php?tipo=risks",
    "label": "Rischi",
    "icon": "fas fa-exclamation",
    "data_attribute": "",
    "parent": "Risk Management"
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "nome": "issues",
    "url": "items.php?tipo=issues",
    "label": "Issue",
    "icon": "fas fa-fire",
    "data_attribute": "",
    "parent": "Risk Management"
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "nome": "changerequests",
    "url": "items.php?tipo=changerequests",
    "label": "Change Requests",
    "icon": "fas fa-plus",
    "data_attribute": "",
    "parent": "Risk Management"
  }
]

const itemsMap = items.reduce((acc, item) => {
  // add it to the map if it has a nome
  if (item.hasOwnProperty('nome')) {
    acc[item.nome] = item;
  }
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(itemsMap.fullcalendar ? .url)
```

https://playcode.io/1482928

Answer (score -1):

```js
[
    {"id":1,"nome":"smartform","url":"smartform.php","label":"Dashboard","icon":"fas fa-th-large","data_attribute":"","parent":"Smartform"},
    {"id":2,"nome":"form_wizard","url":"form_wizard.php","label":"Crea uno Smartform","icon":"fas fa-plus","data_attribute":"data-action=\"create\" data-step=\"0\" data-token=\"0\"","parent":"Smartform"},
    {"id":3,"nome":"fullcalendar","url":"fullcalendar.php","label":"Calendario","icon":"far fa-calendar","data_attribute":"","parent":"Tools"},
    {"id":4,"nome":"gantt","url":"gantt.php","label":"Gantt","icon":"fas fa-stream","data_attribute":"","parent":"Tools"},
    {"id":5,"nome":"timesheet","url":"timesheet.php","label":"Timesheet","icon":"fas fa-hourglass","data_attribute":"","parent":"Tools"},
    {"id":6,"nome":"kanban","url":"kanban.php","label":"Kanban","icon":"fas fa-list-ul","data_attribute":"","parent":"Tools"},
    {"id":7,"nome":"openpoints","url":"items.php?tipo=openpoints","label":"Open Points","icon":"fas fa-keyboard","data_attribute":"","parent":"Risk Management"},
    {"id":8,"nome":"risks","url":"items.php?tipo=risks","label":"Rischi","icon":"fas fa-exclamation","data_attribute":"","parent":"Risk Management"},
    {"id":9,"nome":"issues","url":"items.php?tipo=issues","label":"Issue","icon":"fas fa-fire","data_attribute":"","parent":"Risk Management"},
    {"id":10,"nome":"changerequests","url":"items.php?tipo=changerequests","label":"Change Requests","icon":"fas fa-plus","data_attribute":"","parent":"Risk Management"}
].filter(ele => ele.nome === "fullcalendar")[0].url
```

1. `filter`
   you can get elements that fits your option you provided in filter() function. you can get more in this docs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
2. `[0]`
   If you want one item from it, you should get first item by index slicing. But you need to handle the case that filtered array's length is 0. then [0] might be undefined.
3. `.url`
   you can access to property by `.`.