# Find a value in side a associated array

Tags: javascript

I have a array like this

```
[{"name":"Typical value Sydney (SUA) Houses", "value":"Bar" },
 {"name":"Days on market Sydney (SUA) Houses", "value":"Bar" },
 {"name":"Typical value Melbourne (SUA) Houses", "value":"Line" },
 {"name":"Days on market Brisbane (SUA) Houses", "value":"Bar" }]
```

I have another variable that I receive the name "Days on market Sydney (SUA) Houses"
I want to find the the name in the array and get the corresponded value like "Bar"

how do I achieve this in javascript

```
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
        if (arr[j].name == seri){
             value= arr[j].value;
             return true;
        }}
```

it is not going into the if condition .

Comment: That's the way you do it.  Remember that the spelling must match EXACTLY.  I'm guessing that's what your problem is.

Comment: What do you want to do with the value once found?

Comment: Does this asnwer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462318/find-a-value-in-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Comment: What the output you want? it will output "Bar", which is the value corresponding to the name "Days on market Sydney (SUA) Houses" in the array? Is like that? So when ```console.log(value)//Output:"Bar"```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use the `Array.find` method in JavaScript.

```js
const temp = [
  { name: "Typical value Sydney (SUA) Houses", value: "Bar" },
  { name: "Days on market Sydney (SUA) Houses", value: "Bar" },
  { name: "Typical value Melbourne (SUA) Houses", value: "Line" },
  { name: "Days on market Brisbane (SUA) Houses", value: "Bar" },
];

const toFind = "Days on market Sydney (SUA) Houses";
const ans = temp.find((el) => el.name === toFind);
console.log(ans);
console.log(ans?.value) //To get the value
```

Answer (score 0):

via `Array.prototype.find()`, then can search for a specific object in the array

```js
var array=[{name:"Typical value Sydney (SUA) Houses",value:"Bar"},{name:"Days on market Sydney (SUA) Houses",value:"Bar"},{name:"Typical value Melbourne (SUA) Houses",value:"Line"},{name:"Days on market Brisbane (SUA) Houses",value:"Bar"}];
    
  var b = array.find(function(a) {
    return "Days on market Sydney (SUA) Houses" === a.name;
  });

  // B now have the object with the corresponding name and value

  console.log(b.value);  // output will be Bar
```

Comment: thank you for your response. But when I run it from my application after modification like, assume 'lvalue ='[{name:"Typical value Sydney (SUA) Houses",value:"Bar"},{name:"Days on market Sydney (SUA) Houses",value:"Bar"},{name:"Typical value Melbourne (SUA) Houses",value:"Line"},{name:"Days on market Brisbane (SUA) Houses",value:"Bar"}]''  then modify your code to var array = lvalue; and run the code it gives me error as find is not a function.